# JavaScript object shows as a string instead of an item

Tags: javascript, object

So i am trying to display a data from an API using JavaScript but got an `undefined` instead when i console.log(data) what i am getting is like below. its an object but some how its encapsulate as a string? Any idea how to covert this into a actual object i am new with JavaScript `api` so i am a bit confused.

```
 {"msg":"{\"part\":\"test\",\"station\":\"test2\"}"}
```

I already tried to de serialize the data using `JSON.parse(data)` but no luck.

Comment: do `a['msg'] = JSON.parse(a['msg'])` I guess

Comment: Assuming your data is storied in a variable `data` you need to parse it as

`JSON.parse(data.msg)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have posted is actually an object with a property `msg` which is a strigified JSON. In order to get proper json from this try `obj.msg = JSON.parse(obj.msg);` Assuming `obj` is the response variable you can name it what you want.

See below snippet.

```
{"msg":"{\"part\":\"test\",\"station\":\"test2\"}"}
```

```js
const obj = {"msg":"{\"part\":\"test\",\"station\":\"test2\"}"} ;
console.log('Before parsing:' + typeof obj.msg); // string
obj.msg = JSON.parse(obj.msg);
console.log('After Parsing:' + typeof obj.msg); // object
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse` transforms a string-like-object to the object. So, it expects the whole of the object as a string. Which is not happening in your case.

You have an object key `msg` and its value is a string-like-object. So You need to convert the `msg` value to the **JSON**.

a couple of ways to try -

`let resp = JSON.parse(data.msg)`

or

`return JSON.parse(data.msg)`